# How to turn all embedded images into linked images

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a Word document with a large number of embedded images. To make version control easier I would like to save the document as XML and store all images separately (linked).

In the docx format the images are stored separately inside the zip, but I have not yet found a way to use those files uncompressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have extracted the files from `.docx` (by renaming it to `.zip`). Then I saved my document as Word XML and in a text editor I've removed the `<pkg:package>` elements containing the binary data of the images and added the tag `TargetMode="External"` to the `<Relationship>` elements. Adding the TargetMode was quite easy using a search & replace because all images were named `media/image...`.

After that I discovered that `.gif` files were saved as `.png` in the docx, so I had to change the extensions of those files in the xml.

For Word 2013 you also need to change the tags `<a:embed ...` to `<a:link ...` for it to work (with relative paths).

Comment: nice to hear you solved the problem. Please up-vote the answer if it helped you find the solution.

Comment: @Adam: I was already aware of the fact that I could rename docx to zip, hence my remark that the files are separately in the docx in the question. My problem was with how to create a XML document that referenced those files externally. Thanks for your help anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the DOCX file as a .zip and open it using any standard program like Winzip. You can then extract all images from document\media to your hard drive. From there you will need to work out how to automate (most likely via macro) the replacement of the embedded images to the linked ones on the hard drive.